# LightInject version 4.0.11 Fails to build in MSBuild and does not seem to be added to the portable class library by nuget

Tags: tfs, msbuild

Hi the newer version(s) 4.0.10 & 4.0.11 compile and build fine locally but are rejected with an assembly reference error when automatically built via TFS. After checking the build folder the package just does not exist. This is an MVC project

I have also used this version in another WEB.API project and the project built correctly.

Am I missing something?

update - log file from build:

```
Build started 26/07/2016 16:08:29.
     1>Project "D:\Builds\1002\iChoose\IChoose Assembly\src\iChoose\Development\InitialDev\IChoose.Assembly.Application\IChoose.Assembly.Application.sln" on node 1 (default targets).
 1>ValidateSolutionConfiguration:
     Building solution configuration "Debug|Any CPU".
 1>Project "D:\Builds\1002\iChoose\IChoose Assembly\src\iChoose\Development\InitialDev\IChoose.Assembly.Application\IChoose.Assembly.Application.sln" (1) is building "D:\Builds\1002\iChoose\IChoose Assembly\src\iChoose\Development\InitialDev\IChoose.Assembly.Application\IChoose.Assembly.Application.Tests\IChoose.Assembly.Application.Tests.csproj" (2) on node 2 (default targets).
 2>PrepareForBuild:
     Creating directory "obj\Debug\".
 1>Project "D:\Builds\1002\iChoose\IChoose Assembly\src\iChoose\Development\InitialDev\IChoose.Assembly.Application\IChoose.Assembly.Application.sln" (1) is building "D:\Builds\1002\iChoose\IChoose Assembly\src\iChoose\Development\InitialDev\IChoose.Assembly.Application\IChoose.Assembly.Application\IChoose.Assembly.Application.csproj" (3) on node 1 (default targets).
 3>PrepareForBuild:
     Creating directory "obj\Debug\".
   ResolveAssemblyReferences:
     Primary reference "LightInject, Version=4.0.11.0, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL".
 3>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\bin\amd64\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1697,5): warning MSB3245: Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "LightInject, Version=4.0.11.0, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors. [D:\Builds\1002\iChoose\IChoose Assembly\src\iChoose\Development\InitialDev\IChoose.Assembly.Application\IChoose.Assembly.Application\IChoose.Assembly.Application.csproj]
             For SearchPath "{CandidateAssemblyFiles}".
             Considered "D:\Builds\1002\iChoose\IChoose Assembly\src\iChoose\Development\InitialDev\IChoose.Assembly.Application\packages\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.1.0.0\build\..\tools\csc.exe", but its name "csc" didn't match.
             Considered "D:\Builds\1002\iChoose\IChoose Assembly\src\iChoose\Development\InitialDev\IChoose.Assembly.Application\packages\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.1.0.0\build\..\tools\Microsoft.Build.Tasks.CodeAnalysis.dll", but its name "Microsoft.Build.Tasks.CodeAnalysis" didn't match.
             Considered "D:\Builds\1002\iChoose\IChoose Assembly\src\iChoose\Development\InitialDev\IChoose.Assembly.Application\packages\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.1.0.0\build\..\tools\Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.dll", but its name "Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp" didn't match.
             Considered "D:\Builds\1002\iChoose\IChoose Assembly\src\iChoose\Development\InitialDev\IChoose.Assembly.Application\packages\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.1.0.0\build\..\tools\Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.dll", but its name "Microsoft.CodeAnalysis" didn't match.
             Considered "D:\Builds\1002\iChoose\IChoose Assembly\src\iChoose\Development\InitialDev\IChoose.Assembly.Application\packages\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.1.0.0\build\..\tools\Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.VisualBasic.dll", but its name "Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.VisualBasic" didn't match.
             Considered "D:\Builds\1002\iChoose\IChoose Assembly\src\iChoose\Development\InitialDev\IChoose.Assembly.Application\packages\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.1.0.0\build\..\tools\System.Collections.Immutable.dll", but its name "System.Collections.Immutable" didn't match.
             Considered "D:\Builds\1002\iChoose\IChoose Assembly\src\iChoose\Development\InitialDev\IChoose.Assembly.Application\packages\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.1.0.0\build\..\tools\System.Reflection.Metadata.dll", but its name "System.Reflection.Metadata" didn't match.
             Considered "D:\Builds\1002\iChoose\IChoose Assembly\src\iChoose\Development\InitialDev\IChoose.Assembly.Application\packages\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.1.0.0\build\..\tools\vbc.exe", but its name "vbc" didn't match.
             Considered "D:\Builds\1002\iChoose\IChoose Assembly\src\iChoose\Development\InitialDev\IChoose.Assembly.Application\packages\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.1.0.0\build\..\tools\VBCSCompiler.exe", but its name "VBCSCompiler" didn't match.
             For SearchPath "{HintPathFromItem}".
             Considered "..\..\packages\LightInject.4.0.11\lib\net45\LightInject.dll", but it didn't exist.
             For SearchPath "{TargetFrameworkDirectory}".
             Considered "C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5.2\LightInject.winmd", but it didn't exist.
             Considered "C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5.2\LightInject.dll", but it didn't exist.
             Considered "C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5.2\LightInject.exe", but it didn't exist.
             Considered "C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5.2\Facades\LightInject.winmd", but it didn't exist.
             Considered "C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5.2\Facades\LightInject.dll", but it didn't exist.
             Considered "C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5.2\Facades\LightInject.exe", but it didn't exist.
             For SearchPath "{Registry:Software\Microsoft\.NETFramework,v4.5.2,AssemblyFoldersEx}".
             Considered AssemblyFoldersEx locations.
             For SearchPath "{AssemblyFolders}".
             Considered "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\SDK\Assemblies\LightInject.winmd", but it didn't exist.
             Considered "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\SDK\Assemblies\LightInject.dll", but it didn't exist.
             Considered "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\SDK\Assemblies\LightInject.exe", but it didn't exist.
             Considered "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\SDK\Assemblies\LightInject.winmd", but it didn't exist.
             Considered "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\SDK\Assemblies\LightInject.dll", but it didn't exist.
             Considered "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\SDK\Assemblies\LightInject.exe", but it didn't exist.
             Considered "C:\Program Files\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\LightInject.winmd", but it didn't exist.
             Considered "C:\Program Files\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\LightInject.dll", but it didn't exist.
             Considered "C:\Program Files\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\LightInject.exe", but it didn't exist.
             Considered "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSAS11.GOTFS\OLAP\bin\LightInject.winmd", but it didn't exist.
             Considered "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSAS11.GOTFS\OLAP\bin\LightInject.dll", but it didn't exist.
             Considered "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSAS11.GOTFS\OLAP\bin\LightInject.exe", but it didn't exist.
             Considered "C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\v3.5\LightInject.winmd", but it didn't exist.
             Considered "C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\v3.5\LightInject.dll", but it didn't exist.
             Considered "C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\v3.5\LightInject.exe", but it didn't exist.
             Considered "C:\Program Files\Microsoft.NET\ADOMD.NET\110\LightInject.winmd", but it didn't exist.
             Considered "C:\Program Files\Microsoft.NET\ADOMD.NET\110\LightInject.dll", but it didn't exist.
             Considered "C:\Program Files\Microsoft.NET\ADOMD.NET\110\LightInject.exe", but it didn't exist.
             For SearchPath "{GAC}".
             Considered "LightInject, Version=4.0.11.0, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL", which was not found in the GAC.
             For SearchPath "{RawFileName}".
             Considered treating "LightInject, Version=4.0.11.0, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL" as a file name, but it didn't exist.
             For SearchPath "D:\Builds\1002\iChoose\IChoose Assembly\bin\".
             Considered "D:\Builds\1002\iChoose\IChoose Assembly\bin\LightInject.winmd", but it didn't exist.
             Considered "D:\Builds\1002\iChoose\IChoose Assembly\bin\LightInject.dll", but it didn't exist.
             Considered "D:\Builds\1002\iChoose\IChoose Assembly\bin\LightInject.exe", but it didn't exist.
     AssemblyFoldersEx location: "{Registry:Software\Microsoft\.NETFramework,v4.5.2,AssemblyFoldersEx}"
             C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\MSBuild\v14.0
             C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\MSBuild\v12.0
             C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Web Tools\ReferenceAssemblies\12.0\
             C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\v4.5\
             C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\PublicAssemblies\
             C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft.NET\Primary Interop Assemblies\
             C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\FSharp\.NETFramework\v4.0\4.3.0.0\Type Providers\
             C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\FSharp\.NETFramework\v4.0\4.3.0.0\
             C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\FSharp\.NETFramework\v4.0\4.3.1.0\
             C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Expression\Blend\.NETFramework\v4.5\Prototyping\Libraries\
             C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Expression\Blend\.NETFramework\v4.5\Libraries\
             C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Workflow Manager\1.0\
             C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft WCF Data Services\5.6\bin\.NETFramework\
             C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\VSTO40\v4.0.Framework\
             C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Visual Studio Tools for Office\PIA\Office15\
             C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Visual Studio Tools for Office\PIA\Office14\
             C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Visual Studio Tools for Office\PIA\Common\
             C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\SharePoint\PublicAssemblies\
             C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\v4.0\
             C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\v4.0\
             C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V110\
             C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DTS\Tasks
             C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DTS\PipelineComponents\
             C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DTS\ForEachEnumerators
             C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DTS\Connections\
             C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\TEMPLATE\WorkflowActivities\

             C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\15\TEMPLATE\WorkflowActivities\
             C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\
             C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\15\ISAPI\
             C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\RIA Services\v1.0\Libraries\Server\
             C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\ReportViewer\
             C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\PublicAssemblies\
             C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft.NET\Primary Interop Assemblies\
             C:\Program Files (x86)\Open XML SDK\V2.5\lib
             C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\FSharp\.NETFramework\v4.0\4.3.0.0\Type Providers\
             C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\FSharp\.NETFramework\v4.0\4.3.0.0\
             C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\FSharp\.NETFramework\v4.0\4.3.1.0\
             C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Expression\Blend\.NETFramework\v4.0\Prototyping\Libraries\
             C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Expression\Blend\.NETFramework\v4.0\Libraries\
             C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET Web Pages\v2.0\Assemblies\
             C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET MVC 4\Assemblies\

             C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Microsoft Identity Extensions\1.0\
             C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\SharePoint\PublicAssemblies\
             C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\v2.0\
             C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\v2.0\
             C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\ReportViewer\
             C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\MSEnv\PublicAssemblies\
             C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Chart Controls\Assemblies
             C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\FSharp\.NETFramework\v2.0\2.3.0.0\
             C:\Program Files (x86)\DevExpress 2009.3\Components\Sources\DevExpress.DLL\
             C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DTS\Tasks
             C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DTS\PipelineComponents\
             C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DTS\ForEachEnumerators
             C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DTS\Connections\
   GenerateTargetFrameworkMonikerAttribute:
   Skipping target "GenerateTargetFrameworkMonikerAttribute" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
   CoreCompile:
     D:\Builds\1002\iChoose\IChoose Assembly\src\iChoose\Development\InitialDev\IChoose.Assembly.Application\packages\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.1.0.0\build\..\tools\csc.exe /noconfig /nowarn:1701,1702 /nostdlib+ /errorreport:prompt /warn:4 /define:DEBUG;TRACE /highentropyva+ /reference:"D:\Builds\1002\iChoose\IChoose Assembly\src\iChoose\Development\InitialDev\IChoose.Assembly.Application\packages\Antlr.3.4.1.9004\lib\Antlr3.Runtime.dll" /reference:"D:\Builds\1002\iChoose\IChoose Assembly\src\iChoose\Development\InitialDev\IChoose.Assembly.Application\packages\EntityFramework.6.1.3\lib\net45\EntityFramework.dll" /reference:"D:\Builds\1002\iChoose\IChoose Assembly\src\iChoose\Development\InitialDev\IChoose.Assembly.Application\packages\EntityFramework.6.1.3\lib\net45\EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll" /reference:"D:\Builds\1002\iChoose\IChoose Assembly\src\iChoose\Development\InitialDev\IChoose.Assembly.Application\packages\LightInject.Mvc.1.0.0.4\lib\net45\LightInject.Mvc.dll" /reference:"D:\Builds\1002\iChoose\IChoose Assembly\src\iChoose\Development\InitialDev\IChoose.Assembly.Application\packages\LightInject.Web.1.0.0.4\lib\net45\LightInject.Web.dll" /reference:"D:\Builds\1002\iChoose\IChoose Assembly\src\iChoose\Development\InitialDev\IChoose.Assembly.Application\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core.2.2.1\lib\net45\Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core.dll" /reference:"D:\Builds\1002\iChoose\IChoose Assembly\src\iChoose\Development\InitialDev\IChoose.Assembly.Application\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.2.2.1\lib\net45\Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.dll" /reference:"D:\Builds\1002\iChoose\IChoose Assembly\src\iChoose\Development\InitialDev\IChoose.Assembly.Application\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin.2.2.1\lib\net45\Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin.dll" /reference:"D:\Builds\1002\iChoose\IChoose Assembly\src\iChoose\Development\InitialDev\IChoose.Assembly.Application\packages\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.1.0.0\lib\net45\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5.2\Microsoft.CSharp.dll" /reference:"D:\Builds\1002\iChoose\IChoose Assembly\src\iChoose\Development\InitialDev\IChoose.Assembly.Application\packages\Microsoft.Owin.3.0.1\lib\net45\Microsoft.Owin.dll" /reference:"D:\Builds\1002\iChoose\IChoose Assembly\src\iChoose\Development\InitialDev\IChoose.Assembly.Application\packages\Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.3.0.1\lib\net45\Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.dll" /reference:"D:\Builds\1002\iChoose\IChoose Assembly\src\iChoose\Development\InitialDev\IChoose.Assembly.Application\packages\Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies.3.0.1\lib\net45\Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies.dll" /reference:"D:\Builds\1002\iChoose\IChoose Assembly\src\iChoose\Development\InitialDev\IChoose.Assembly.Application\packages\Microsoft.Owin.Security.3.0.1\lib\net45\Microsoft.Owin.Security.dll" /reference:"D:\Builds\1002\iChoose\IChoose Assembly\src\iChoose\Development\InitialDev\IChoose.Assembly.Application\packages\Microsoft.Owin.Security.Facebook.3.0.1\lib\net45\Microsoft.Owin.Security.Facebook.dll" /reference:"D:\Builds\1002\iChoose\IChoose Assembly\src\iChoose\Development\InitialDev\IChoose.Assembly.Application\packages\Microsoft.Owin.Security.Google.3.0.1\lib\net45\Microsoft.Owin.Security.Google.dll" /reference:"D:\Builds\1002\iChoose\IChoose Assembly\src\iChoose\Development\InitialDev\IChoose.Assembly.Application\packages\Microsoft.Owin.Security.MicrosoftAccount.3.0.1\lib\net45\Microsoft.Owin.Security.MicrosoftAccount.dll" /reference:"D:\Builds\1002\iChoose\IChoose Assembly\src\iChoose\Development\InitialDev\IChoose.Assembly.Application\packages\Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth.3.0.1\lib\net45\Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth.dll" /reference:"D:\Builds\1002\iChoose\IChoose Assembly\src\iChoose\Development\InitialDev\IChoose.Assembly.Application\packages\Microsoft.Owin.Security.Twitter.3.0.1\lib\net45\Microsoft.Owin.Security.Twitter.dll" /reference:"D:\Builds\1002\iChoose\IChoose Assembly\src\iChoose\Development\InitialDev\IChoose.Assembly.Application\packages\Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.1.0.0.0\lib\net40\Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5.2\mscorlib.dll" /reference:"D:\Builds\1002\iChoose\IChoose Assembly\src\iChoose\Development\InitialDev\IChoose.Assembly.Application\packages\Newtonsoft.Json.6.0.4\lib\net45\Newtonsoft.Json.dll" /reference:"D:\Builds\1002\iChoose\IChoose Assembly\src\iChoose\Development\InitialDev\IChoose.Assembly.Application\packages\Owin.1.0\lib\net40\Owin.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5.2\System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5.2\System.Configuration.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5.2\System.Core.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5.2\System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5.2\System.Data.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5.2\System.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5.2\System.Drawing.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5.2\System.EnterpriseServices.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5.2\System.Net.Http.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5.2\System.Net.Http.WebRequest.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5.2\System.Web.Abstractions.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5.2\System.Web.ApplicationServices.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5.2\System.Web.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5.2\System.Web.DynamicData.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5.2\System.Web.Entity.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5.2\System.Web.Extensions.dll" /reference:"D:\Builds\1002\iChoose\IChoose Assembly\src\iChoose\Development\InitialDev\IChoose.Assembly.Application\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages.3.2.3\lib\net45\System.Web.Helpers.dll" /reference:"D:\Builds\1002\iChoose\IChoose Assembly\src\iChoose\Development\InitialDev\IChoose.Assembly.Application\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.5.2.3\lib\net45\System.Web.Mvc.dll" /reference:"D:\Builds\1002\iChoose\IChoose Assembly\src\iChoose\Development\InitialDev\IChoose.Assembly.Application\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization.1.1.3\lib\net40\System.Web.Optimization.dll" /reference:"D:\Builds\1002\iChoose\IChoose Assembly\src\iChoose\Development\InitialDev\IChoose.Assembly.Application\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.Razor.3.2.3\lib\net45\System.Web.Razor.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5.2\System.Web.Routing.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5.2\System.Web.Services.dll" /reference:"D:\Builds\1002\iChoose\IChoose Assembly\src\iChoose\Development\InitialDev\IChoose.Assembly.Application\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages.3.2.3\lib\net45\System.Web.WebPages.Deployment.dll" /reference:"D:\Builds\1002\iChoose\IChoose Assembly\src\iChoose\Development\InitialDev\IChoose.Assembly.Application\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages.3.2.3\lib\net45\System.Web.WebPages.dll" /reference:"D:\Builds\1002\iChoose\IChoose Assembly\src\iChoose\Development\InitialDev\IChoose.Assembly.Application\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages.3.2.3\lib\net45\System.Web.WebPages.Razor.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5.2\System.Xml.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5.2\System.Xml.Linq.dll" /reference:"D:\Builds\1002\iChoose\IChoose Assembly\src\iChoose\Development\InitialDev\IChoose.Assembly.Application\packages\WebGrease.1.5.2\lib\WebGrease.dll" /debug+ /debug:full /optimize- /out:obj\Debug\IChoose.Assembly.Application.dll /subsystemversion:6.00 /target:library /utf8output App_Start\BundleConfig.cs App_Start\FilterConfig.cs App_Start\IdentityConfig.cs App_Start\RouteConfig.cs App_Start\Startup.Auth.cs Controllers\AccountController.cs Controllers\HomeController.cs Controllers\ManageController.cs Global.asax.cs Models\AccountViewModels.cs Models\IdentityModels.cs Models\ManageViewModels.cs Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs Startup.cs "C:\Users\TFSBUILD\AppData\Local\Temp\.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2.AssemblyAttributes.cs"
 3>Startup.cs(30,33): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'ServiceContainer' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [D:\Builds\1002\iChoose\IChoose Assembly\src\iChoose\Development\InitialDev\IChoose.Assembly.Application\IChoose.Assembly.Application\IChoose.Assembly.Application.csproj]
 3>Done Building Project "D:\Builds\1002\iChoose\IChoose Assembly\src\iChoose\Development\InitialDev\IChoose.Assembly.Application\IChoose.Assembly.Application\IChoose.Assembly.Application.csproj" (default targets) -- FAILED.
 2>Done Building Project "D:\Builds\1002\iChoose\IChoose Assembly\src\iChoose\Development\InitialDev\IChoose.Assembly.Application\IChoose.Assembly.Application.Tests\IChoose.Assembly.Application.Tests.csproj" (default targets) -- FAILED.
 1>Done Building Project "D:\Builds\1002\iChoose\IChoose Assembly\src\iChoose\Development\InitialDev\IChoose.Assembly.Application\IChoose.Assembly.Application.sln" (default targets) -- FAILED.

Build FAILED.

   "D:\Builds\1002\iChoose\IChoose Assembly\src\iChoose\Development\InitialDev\IChoose.Assembly.Application\IChoose.Assembly.Application.sln" (default target) (1) ->
   "D:\Builds\1002\iChoose\IChoose Assembly\src\iChoose\Development\InitialDev\IChoose.Assembly.Application\IChoose.Assembly.Application\IChoose.Assembly.Application.csproj" (default target) (3) ->
   (ResolveAssemblyReferences target) -> 
     C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\bin\amd64\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1697,5): warning MSB3245: Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "LightInject, Version=4.0.11.0, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors. [D:\Builds\1002\iChoose\IChoose Assembly\src\iChoose\Development\InitialDev\IChoose.Assembly.Application\IChoose.Assembly.Application\IChoose.Assembly.Application.csproj]


   "D:\Builds\1002\iChoose\IChoose Assembly\src\iChoose\Development\InitialDev\IChoose.Assembly.Application\IChoose.Assembly.Application.sln" (default target) (1) ->
   "D:\Builds\1002\iChoose\IChoose Assembly\src\iChoose\Development\InitialDev\IChoose.Assembly.Application\IChoose.Assembly.Application\IChoose.Assembly.Application.csproj" (default target) (3) ->
   (CoreCompile target) -> 
     Startup.cs(30,33): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'ServiceContainer' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [D:\Builds\1002\iChoose\IChoose Assembly\src\iChoose\Development\InitialDev\IChoose.Assembly.Application\IChoose.Assembly.Application\IChoose.Assembly.Application.csproj]

1 Warning(s)
1 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:00:47.42
```

Comment: I have had to revert to version 4.0.9 and it now builds as it should, but I am still curious as to why this is happening.

Comment: Did you use the latest Nuget release? https://www.nuget.org/

Comment: Yes it is the lastest nuget release. I think that may be the issue due to the fact that it works on a WEB.API project that was done before i updated nuget. I am using VS 2015 and the Nuget package manger is showing me 3.5.0

Answer (score 0):

Try to check whether you are using the latest nuget release.

Comment: As mentioned above it is the latest for the version of VS i use. I have looked at the package contents and there is a marked difference in the content in the version jump from 9 to 10. I am not at all sure this makes any difference.

Comment: Nuget 3.5.0 is a beta version, try 3.4.4 version, which should be shipped in VS 2015.3.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Unfortunately I Have also tried this on a colleagues machine who has 3.4.4. He downloaded the project afresh re-applied the package and still the same issue.

Comment: yes what is the best way in which to get it to you?

Comment: You can post the log here with the sensitive information erased.

Comment: The log is too big to post, I will try and post the relevant info.

Comment: 3>PrepareForBuild:
         Creating directory "obj\Debug\".
       ResolveAssemblyReferences:
         Primary reference "LightInject, Version=4.0.11.0, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL".
     3>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\bin\amd64\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1697,5): warning MSB3245: Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "LightInject, Version=4.0.11.0, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors.

Comment: For SearchPath "{HintPathFromItem}".
                 Considered "..\..\packages\LightInject.4.0.11\lib\net45\LightInject.dll", but it didn't exist.
                 For SearchPath "{TargetFrameworkDirectory}".
                 Considered "C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5.2\LightInject.winmd", but it didn't exist.

Comment: it then goes through various locations to try and find the dll

Comment: Startup.cs(30,33): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'ServiceContainer' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [D:\Builds\1002\iChoose\IChoose Assembly\src\iChoose\Development\InitialDev\IChoose.Assembly.Application\IChoose.Assembly.Application\IChoose.Assembly.Application.csproj]

Comment: this is the final fail - ServiceContainer is the 1st instance of calling the dll

Comment: Hi, you can add the log in your original post by editing it.

Comment: doh - sorry yes did not think